# Error 7373 connecting to SSAS 2008 only from one machine

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

Within the last week, I've gotten the following error when trying to use a linked server in SSMS (tried 2008 and 2012) to connect to a SSAS 2008 R2 instance on our cluster:

> Cannot set initialization properties for OLE DB provider 'MSOLAP' for
>   linked server ....  returned message "The following system error
>   occurred: ." (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7373)

It's not related to my login, because I can use it fine from other servers as well as SQL agent jobs.  Found some googling suggesting a DNS issue, but using linked servers with the fully-qualified name as well as IP address doesn't make a difference.  Ports are open and listening on the server, and "Allow Inprocess" is enabled for MSOLAP on both SSMS 2008 & 2012.

My machine is Win7. I've been testing from Win2008 servers; other machines with Win7 do not have this issue.

I see a few hits on the web about this issue but ZERO about resolutions. Anyone have any ideas what else I can try?